# CSS - Making an image a circle, with a border, has a small space inbetween

Tags: css

I am trying to create an image, in a circle shape, with a border around it. The problem is that if you look VERY carefully between the image and the border, there seems to be a small space.

Is is possible somehow to make the border attach itself perfectly to the circle shape?

Here is a small codepen:

https://codepen.io/dbugger/pen/NjYMEQ

This is the CSS used:

```
img {
  border-radius: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px black;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What browser does this appear on? Or does it appear on all browsers?

Comment: I added an image. I am running Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, this happens also in Edge. Can't you just use `border: 10px solid black` in your case? Works the same but without the space.

Comment: It's a matter of rendering, [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54770/why-would-i-get-aliasing-on-a-vector-like-this) would also apply to this effect.

Comment: Could be an artifact from anti-aliasing of an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give image the same background-color (whatever that is, I used maroon here) like this:

```css
img {
  border-radius: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px black;
  background-color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/300/300" alt="" />
```

Comment: I guess the real case would be a real image not a plain colored one.

Comment: Indeed, but instead of the color of the image, I can use the color of the border